# Reading .tar.Z file without decompressing in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, tarfile

I am new to Python and trying to read .tar.Z file name and trying to list the file names compressed inside it. I just need to know the file name and size. I am using Python 2.7. I am able to do it with .tar file. Can somebody explain that with an example?

Thanks

Comment: I have checked for zlib and gzip and zipfile but it does not support reading it directly from .Z file. It seems we just have to read it from the .tar file after decompressing it from .Z. Decompressing of .Z can be done easily though. So still i didn't get what i was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `compress` command and its `.Z` files is so antiquated that Python [doesn't support it directly](https://docs.python.org/2/library/archiving.html) (and likely never did).

I suggest

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.tar.Z; do
    tarname=`basename "$i" .Z`
    uncompress "$i"
    gzip "$tarname"
done
```

Then you can just open the [tarfiles as shown in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/tarfile.html) with the `'r:gz'` mode.

If you don't want to migrate away from 1980s compress technology, then you should probably look into

```
zcat tarfile.tar.Z | tar tf -
```

using the [subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

(For those who are tempted to say "but bzip2 is better" or "but xz is supported in Python 3", yeah, I agree, but gzip is simply more standard).